# What do the currently undocumented values "atom", "corei7", "corei7-avx" and "slm" do for "-march" option in gcc?

Tags: gcc

One of the options that can be passed to the GCC compiler is `-march=cpu-type`.

According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-march-16), this option will cause the GCC to

> Generate instructions for the machine type *cpu-type*. In contrast to `-mtune=cpu-type`, which merely tunes the generated code for the specified *cpu-type*, `-march=cpu-type` allows GCC to generate code that may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated. Specifying `-march=cpu-type` implies `-mtune=cpu-type`, except where noted otherwise.

The same documentation page lists possible valid `cpu-type` options, but it does not include options `atom`, `corei7`, `corei7-avx` and `slm`.

Nevertheless, running GCC with these values for `-march=` works, so what do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the values for GCC's `-march` option are aliased to other cpu-type values:

| Value | Alias |
| --- | --- |
| `atom` | `bonnell` |
| `corei7` | `nehalem` |
| `corei7-avx` | `sandybridge` |
| `core-avx-i` | `sandybridge` |
| `core-avx2` | `haswell` |
| `slm` | `silvermont` |

In GCC-4.8 they were [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options) as

> `corei7`
>
> Intel Core i7 CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1 and SSE4.2 instruction set support.
>
> `corei7-avx`
>
> Intel Core i7 CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AES and PCLMUL instruction set support.
>
> `core-avx-i`
>
> Intel Core CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AES, PCLMUL, FSGSBASE, RDRND and F16C instruction set support.
>
> `core-avx2`
>
> Intel Core CPU with 64-bit extensions, MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, AES, PCLMUL, FSGSBASE, RDRND, FMA, BMI, BMI2 and F16C instruction set support.
>
> `atom`
>
> Intel Atom CPU with 64-bit extensions, MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3 and SSSE3 instruction set support.

This change was introduced by the commit ["Use proper Intel processor names for -march=/-mtune="](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=d3c11974032e21121a051d423a1d71097edf752f)